# Using legend in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, legend

I have a plot in a for loop and I need to use the legend command to label them. I need to create a array of strings to use the same. For some reason it just doesn't seem to work. Can somebody help. I am pasting the code below.

```
   for i = 1:len
   for j = 1:C{i,1}/n
    cc = hsv(12);
    semilogx(w/pi,Same_psd{i,1}(:,j+1),'color',cc(j+1,:))
    str = num2str(Same_mean{i,j+1});
    srt_array = [str_array; str];
    legend(str_array);
   end 
   end
```

Comment: `legend(str_array)` should probably go outside of both `for` loops. Try printing out `str_array` at the end as well - see if it contains the strings that you expect.

Comment: no it doesn't .. the problem lies in concatenating the strings ..

Comment: when I initialize the str_array as str_array = []; its stored as a different variable in the variable space and a new variable which is a string is being created instead of concatenating str value to the existing str_array which I had initialized before

Comment: I think there is a typo in your code. Shouln't `srt_array = [str_array; str];` be `str_array = [str_array; str];` And it's still better (and has the same result) if you place `legend` out of the loop

Comment: Putting strings in arrays doesn't work the way you probably expect in MATLAB – a string is a matrix of characters and you cannot have a matrix containing matrices. If you knew that, the next thing I'd point out is that you should initialize `str_array='';` to get the right data type. (And note that you have a typo in your code above, `srt_array` vs. `str_array`.) If you didn't, try using cell arrays instead, `str_array={};` and inside the loop, `str_array{end+1} = str;`.

Comment: Cell array is the way to go http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
legend_labels = cell(10,1);

for i = 1:10

    h(i) = plot(randn(10,1));
    hold all
    legend_labels{i} = sprintf('This is label #%i', i);

end;

legend(h,legend_labels{:})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the DisplayName property. Has the nice side effect that you can guaranty the legend is in sync with your lines.

eg:

```
clf
hold on
for i = 1:10
    col = rand(3,1);
    semilogx(1:10,rand(10,1),'DisplayName',sprintf('This is curve %i',i),...
    'color',col)
end 
legend('Location','best')
```